# Cordova and Crosswalk - Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

In my Cordova app I'm using Crosswalk plugin.  I'm getting the following error when I attempt to build for android:

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65600 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65600 into a non-jumbo instruction!
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:111)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:74)
        at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
        at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:50)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:826)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:800)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:772)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:669)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:523)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

This seems to occur if I'm using a combination of plugins that are large like camera and phonegap-plugin-push.

I also noticed the following build message:

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It
>   currently has approximately 910 MB. For faster builds, increase the
>   maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB. To do
>   this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
>   gradle.properties. For more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html